# Entity Framework, Adding Data To Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a problem while we are trying all of the data to database. We are using Entity Framework Code First method and SQL Server. Our connections are ready, our tables have been created.

We are keeping our data into List right now. But we cant send it to database. Its our code. When code comes to Save.Changes line, it crushes

**ITS THE ERROR CODE**

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries.
>   See the inner exception for details.

## CONTACT ENTITY

```
public class Contact 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string cn { get; set; }
    public string sn { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string l { get; set; }
    public string st{ get; set; }
    public string title{ get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string physicalDeliveryOfficeName{ get; set; }
    public long? telephoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string givenName{ get; set; }
    public string initials { get; set; }
    public DateTime? whenCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? whenChanged { get; set; }
    public string co{ get; set; }
    public string displayName{ get; set; }
    public int? delivContLength { get; set; }
    public string company{ get; set; }
    public string proxyAdress{ get; set; }
    public string streetAdress{ get; set; }
    public string mailNickname{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int? primaryGroupID { get; set; }
    public string objectGUID { get; set; }
    public string objectSID{ get; set; }
    public string sAMAccountName{ get; set; }
    public string mail{ get; set; }
    public string homePhone { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
}
```

## ENTITY FRAMEWORK PAGE

```
namespace WebApplication5.EntityFramework
{
    public class PhoneDexContext : DbContext

    { 
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SyncInfo> SyncInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## DATABASE SECTION

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = new LdapServiceManager().getAllUsers();
            var phoneDex = new PhoneDexContext();

            foreach (var contact in test)
            {

                //phoneDex.Entry(contact).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                phoneDex.Contacts.Add(contact);

                //TODO HATA ALINIYOR
                phoneDex.SaveChanges();

            }

            return View();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception does it throw? When you have an error, always show the error message and stack trace - it has an answer to a question in 99% times.

Comment: Sorry i forgot it    An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: There is also an InnerException, post its contents as well.

Comment: what is the  inner exception??

Comment: .NET `Exception` object has a property `InnerException` of type `Exception`. So, if your exception is generated because of another exception, or depends on it, you can store it there to describe the problem better. Actually, there can be a long `InnerException`s chain. In case of `EntityFramework`, most errors are located in `InnerException` object. Just use this property to access it: `catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException); }`

Answer (score 1):

It's done guys, thanks.

It's about another database that we didn't create. We are using localhost database's connection string but there was another one which created by template. After deleting template's database, its solved:)